# jQuery Isotope:

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

Is there a way to keep the positioning intact, but making elements non click-able?
demo [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-partial.html).

By adding another class instead of `.element`, I loose the positioning.

Sorry for not adding specific code examples, as I'm not sure where to fix this issue (markup, css or the jquery part)

Comment: See the free masonry here: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
$(yourelement).css("cursor","auto");
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The items are clickable only because there's this bit of script.

```
// change size of clicked element
$container.find('.element').live('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('large');
  $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

You can change the CSS class to whatever you want, so long as it can be matched by the [`itemSelector` option](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#itemselector)

```
$container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.my-class'
});
```

Comment: reading my question again, I realise it wasn't too well explained :)

I want to make some elements clickable (and make them scale, as the demos show), and som of the other elements NON clickable..
so, the same array of elements - but some of them non-clickable..

If I just add a new class similar to the .element, the positioning is lost..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make some elements non clickable you can just check that in the listener

```
var notClickable = ['Hg','Co','Rb']; // these element are not clickable

      // change size of clicked element
      $container.delegate( '.element', 'click', function(){
       //if not in notClickable tab
       if(jQuery.inArray( $(this).attr('data-symbol'), notClickable )==-1){
        $(this).toggleClass('large');
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
       }
      });
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasNDS/bKtvN/1/